# Предисловие и предлог — лингвистические термины?

Tags: лексика, терминология

Каким лингвистическим термином можно назвать калькированные/полукалькированные слова отличающиеся при этом по смыслу, например, *предисловие и предлог*?

Answer (score 2):

Что-то такой термин на ум не приходит.

Каждый из них - **словообразовательная** (**морфемная) калька.**

Можно сказать, что предисловие и предлог - слова с общим семантическим компонентом или с  с общим словообразовательным элементом. Возможно их назвать этимологически родственными, мотивированными общим калькированным источником.

> ПРЕДИСЛОВИЕ  - <вводная часть произведения>, <то, что говорится перед
>   чем-то главным>. Собств. рус. В словарях фиксируется с I пол. XVII в.
>   (ср. в памятниках письменности XII в. предисловие - тожд.). Возникло
>   как калька лат. prologus или непосредственно греч. prologos <пролог>.
>   Это слово заимствовано рус. яз. как пролог <вступление к ^ему-нибудь>
>   в XVIII в. При калькировании pro- использовано ст.-сл. пр-Ьди (пр-Ьдь)
>   <впереди, раньше> (см. впредь), a logos - общеслав. сущ. слово и суф.
>   отвлеч. имен -uj-e. См. перед, перёд, слово.

http://moyslovar.ru/slovari/etimolog_slovar/slovo/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5

**Предлог (часть речи**) -  образовано по методу кальки с греческого prothesis (позиция впереди); **предло́г (повод, основание, причина**) - калька греч. πρόθεσις, лат. рrаероsitiō; то, что положено перед чем-либо.
 https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3